# Context menu will not remain visible using wpf and caliburn

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

Having an issue with a context menu not staying open on button click. Im using wpf and caliburn micro to achieve this. The context menu appears and then disappears immediately.

xaml

```
                <Button.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu x:Name="MainContextMenu" StaysOpen="true" PlacementRectangle="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                        <MenuItem Header="Find" />
                        <MenuItem Header="Add" />
                        <MenuItem Header="View" />
                        <MenuItem Header="Edit" />
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Button.ContextMenu>
                <Image Source="/Images/TrayCogIcon.png">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                            <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="CogButtonClick">
                                <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding ElementName=cogButton}" />
                            </cal:ActionMessage>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </Image>
            </Button>
```

viewmodel

```
        public void CogButtonClick(object sender) 
        {

            var addbutton = sender as System.Windows.Controls.Button;
            if (addbutton != null)
            {

                addbutton.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;

            }
        }
```

Ive tried setting staysOpen to true in both the xaml and the viewmodel but no luck.
Im relatively new to wpf and caliburn so any insight would be helpful! Thanks.

Comment: Context menu is a Popup. Popups closes by default on MouseUp outside the Popup itself.. and that exactly what happens when you your mouse is released from the pressed button.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use a ToggleButton to solve the problem.
You have to add binding to "IsChecked" property of ToggleButton :

```
IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=MainContextMenu, Path=IsOpen}"
```

Additional information, the ContextMenu of the button is displayed natively with a right click on the button.

Full Sample :

```
 <ToggleButton Name="toggleMenu"
                   Width="50" Height="20"
                   IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=MainContextMenu, Path=IsOpen}">
                <ToggleButton.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu x:Name="MainContextMenu" 
                                 PlacementRectangle="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                        <MenuItem Header="Find" />
                        <MenuItem Header="Add" />
                        <MenuItem Header="View" />
                        <MenuItem Header="Edit" />
                    </ContextMenu>
                </ToggleButton.ContextMenu>
    </ToggleButton>
```